# Как защитить музыкальный портал от авторских прав?

Tags: авторские-права

Здравствуйте, собираюсь разрабатывать музыкальный портал, и естественно не хочу судебных тяжб. Каким образом порталы типа youtube защищаются от авторского права?

Comment: Платить деньги праводержателям.

Comment: @jojo97, какие там судебные разбирательства? Музыкальных порталов ныне тьма тьмущая! Ваш "проект" - это лишь капля в море. Думаю, на вашем портале будет находиться не более 200 человек в день, ведь тема не особо актуальная => ни о каких судах и речи быть не может, потому что ваш сайт вряд ли будет найден в этом "море".

Comment: Еще можно запихнуть сервер на борт БПЛА летающего над нейтральными водами мирового океана и таким образом положить на правообладателей.

Comment: Asen. По поводу капли в море. Покажите мне хоть один нормальный музыкальный портал на русском языке. Нормальный, означает, что на нем есть неглючный кроссбраузерный плеер, который продолжает играть после перезагрузки страницы, есть большой выбор из музыки, как отечественной, так и зарубежной, все рассортировано по жанрам, поджанрам и альбомам, а не кучой, с непонятными названиями на транслите, есть автоматическая система предлагающая послушать что-нибудь похожее на то, что сейчас слушает посетитель и свободным скачиванием без всяких файлообменников и без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: @Lucky, это лишь навороты поверх основного...

Comment: @igumnov, у кого-то мелькала уже такая мысль

Comment: youtube многое удаляет и блокирует, т.о. уступая правообладтелям, вам надо смотреть на политику крупных торрентов

Comment: @Asen, очень интересно, как вы оценили мой портал не зная никаких подробностей, кроме того, что он относится к музыке. По секрету, вы обладаете экстрасенсорными способностями?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это вопрос к юристам. Наверное, надо выбрать правильную страну для хостинга сайта, продумать и подготовить пути отступления. Или при хорошей монетизации делиться с крышей, как, наверное, поступает ВК?

Новость в тему: [Ким Дотком обещает создать неуязвимый файлообменник](http://habrahabr.ru/post/155405/)  Шифрование контента до загрузки — хороший вариант. Есть протоколы отдачи шифрованного потока, опять же. Т.е. вариант "загрузил аудиофайл, поделился ключем только с друзьями" — очень привлекателен!

Comment: @sergiks, ВК перекладывает ответственность на пользователей. "Аудиофайл не должен нарушать авторские права."

Comment: То есть, такой дисклеймер может защитить от суда? Что-то подобное я и представлял.

Comment: YouTube и ко. — тоже. Правообладателю должно быть легко пожаловаться на любой файл, и реакция должна быть быстрой. Но без юристов не обойтись.

Comment: Ну первое время можно перекантоваться. Спасибо, @sergiks.